# uploading image buffer with minio

Tags: image, go, amazon-s3, buffer, minio

I am attempting to upload an image.Image (image.NRGBA) to storage space with minio.
Here is my code:

```go
buff := new(bytes.Buffer)

err = png.Encode(buff, image)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("failed to create buffer", err)
}

reader := bytes.NewReader(buff.Bytes())

n, err := minioClient.FPutObject(bucketName, objectName, reader, minio.PutObjectOptions{ContentType:contentType})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

I get the error: cannot use reader (type *bytes.Reader) as type string in argument to minioClient.FPutObject

Comment: The minio package's `FPut*` functions take the *name of a file* (i.e., a string). Use the `PutObject` function to pass in anything that implements `io.Reader`.

Comment: @torek Thank you, it works perfectly now. If you create a reply I can mark this post as solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minio` package's `FPut*` functions take the *name of a file*, i.e., a string. Use the `PutObject` function (or its context variant) to pass in anything that implements `io.Reader`, such as your `reader` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PutObject`.

```
info, err := minioClient.PutObject(ctx, bucketName, objectName, reader, int64(len(bytes))), minio.PutObjectOptions{ContentType: contentType})
```

API doc is at https://docs.min.io/docs/golang-client-api-reference#PutObject